# PHP Function substr Not Working as Expected

Tags: php

I was working on huge strings to extract useful data using PHP. Everything was going well until I encountered this unexpected outcome.

```
echo substr("https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Fapexcalit%2F&amp;redir_token=cQ3kBke8cJRkD9SHj2PKKqMFR598MTUzMTk0NDQ5MkAxNTMxODU4MDky&amp;event=channel_description;",0,50);
```

Output I am getting is

```
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Fapexcalit%2F&ampamp
```

I don't understand where the last ampamp came from in the output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me

Comment: [I can't duplicate it](https://3v4l.org/r0WAu). It may be the way you're outputting it that might be re-encoding the ampersand.

Comment: Substr working well, seems like something wrong with other part of your code. https://3v4l.org/r0WAu , show your code...

Comment: The last `amp` comes from the input string. The extra `amp` is the first one and its source is the `&` that is present in the string and is probably encoded as HTML by some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not reproducible to me though, I would have used `html_entity_decode` instead `substr` in this case. The `html_entity_decode` gives the actual result by coverting all HTML entities to their applicable characters

```
$tst = html_entity_decode("https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Fapexcalit%2F&redir_token=cQ3kBke8cJRkD9SHj2PKKqMFR598MTUzMTk0NDQ5MkAxNTMxODU4MDky&event=channel_description;");
echo substr ($tst, 0, 50);
```

Check here https://3v4l.org/jf5VZ

Read more here 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;` is an HTML entities, try use function `htmlspecialchars_decode()` in your input string.

Like this:

```
$str = "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Fapexcalit%2F&amp;redir_token=cQ3kBke8cJRkD9SHj2PKKqMFR598MTUzMTk0NDQ5MkAxNTMxODU4MDky&amp;event=channel_description;";
$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
echo substr($str, 0, 47);
// Output: https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Fapexcalit%2F&
```